# Error creating OpenCV Non Free build v4.3, collapsable.cpp -errors C2039, 2605

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, sift, opencv-contrib

This may be a simple problem but this is my first use of cmake and first complicated build so I don't know what to try next. My current experience is Python and Java. I have searched Stackoverflow and OpenCV but did not find an answer that I understood enough to solve this problem.

I am trying to build a version of OpenCV on Windows with the non-free code included following this excellent tutorial https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/

I get the following 2 errors in compiling the supplied modules when creating opencv_cvv, there are also multiple warnings.

> Line 1527: 59>C:\path\cvv\src\qtutil../util/observer_ptr.hpp(177,15):
>   error C2039: 'logic_error': is not a member of 'std' (compiling source
>   file C:\path\cvv\src\qtutil\collapsable.cpp)
>
> Line 1532: 59>C:\path\cvv\src\qtutil../util/observer_ptr.hpp(177,1):
>   error C2065: 'logic_error': undeclared identifier (compiling source
>   file C:\path\cvv\src\qtutil\collapsable.cpp)

**Development steps**
Using Visual Studio 2019 and cmake to build, both installed on 22 May 20.
Downloaded OpenCV 4.3.0 and the OpenCV_contrib code on 22 May 20 following the instructions exactly as the tutorial says with one exception, I selected
      OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE

To eliminate the OpenCV_contrib code, and build issues I built succesfully using the tutorial without selecting NONFREE or supplying the path to the extra modules. So the installation and build seem OK.

**OpenCV collapsable.cpp**

```
#include "collapsable.hpp"

namespace cvv
{
namespace qtutil
{

Collapsable::Collapsable(const QString &title, std::unique_ptr<QWidget> widget,
                         bool isCollapsed, QWidget *parent)
    : QFrame{ parent }, widget_{ widget.get() }, layout_{ nullptr }
{
    auto lay = util::make_unique<QVBoxLayout>();
    layout_ = *lay;
    // set alignment+border
    setLineWidth(1);
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
    layout_->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    layout_->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // build header
    auto tmpButton = util::make_unique<QPushButton>();
    button_ = tmpButton.get();
    button_->setEnabled(true);
    button_->setText(title);
    button_->setCheckable(true);

    // build widget
    setLayout(lay.release());
    layout_->addWidget(tmpButton.release());
    layout_->addWidget(widget.release());

    // connect signals and slots
    QObject::connect(button_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,
                     SLOT(toggleVisibility()));

    // collapse/ expand according to isCollapsed
    collapse(isCollapsed);
}

// Collapsable::Collapsable(const QString& title,QWidget& widget, bool
// isCollapsed, QWidget *parent):
//  Collapsable{title, std::unique_ptr<QWidget>{&widget}, isCollapsed,
//parent} {}

void Collapsable::collapse(bool b)
{
    button_->setChecked(!b);
    if (b)
    {
        widget_->hide();
    }
    else
    {
        widget_->show();
    }
}

QWidget *Collapsable::detachWidget()
{
    if (!widget_)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    layout_->removeWidget(widget_);
    QWidget *tmp = widget_;
    widget_ = nullptr;
    return tmp;
}
}
} // end namespaces qtutil, cvv
```

**OpenCV collapsable.hpp**

```
#ifndef CVVISUAL_COLLAPSABLE_H
#define CVVISUAL_COLLAPSABLE_H
// std
#include <cstddef>
// QT
#include <QString>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFrame>

#include "../util/util.hpp"
#include "../util/observer_ptr.hpp"

namespace cvv
{
namespace qtutil
{

/**
 * @brief Contains a widget and a title.
 *
 * The widget can be collapsed and expanded with a button.
 * If the widget is collapsed only button and title are shown.
 */
class Collapsable : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
      public:
    /**
     * @brief Constructs a collapsable
     * @param title The title above the widget.
     * @param widget The widget to store.
     * @param isCollapsed If true the contained widget will be collapsed.
     * (It will be shown
     * otherwise.)
     */
    // explicit Collapsable(const QString& title, QWidget& widget, bool
    // isCollapsed = true,
    //      QWidget *parent = 0);
    explicit Collapsable(const QString &title,
                         std::unique_ptr<QWidget> widget,
                         bool isCollapsed = true, QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~Collapsable()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @brief Collapses the contained widget.
     * @param b
     * @parblock
     *      true: collapses the widget
     *      false: expands the widget
     * @endparblock
     */
    void collapse(bool b = true);

    /**
     * @brief Expands the contained widget.
     * @param b
     * @parblock
     *      true: expands the widget
     *      false: collapses the widget
     * @endparblock
    */
    void expand(bool b = true)
    {
        collapse(!b);
    }

    /**
    * @brief Sets the title above the widget.
    */
    void setTitle(const QString &title)
    {
        button_->setText(title);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Returns the current title above the widget.
     * @return The current title above the widget
     */
    QString title() const
    {
        return button_->text();
    }

    /**
     * @brief Returns a reference to the contained widget.
     * @return A reference to the contained widget.
     */
    QWidget &widget()
    {
        return *widget_;
    }

    const QWidget &widget() const
    {
        return *widget_;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Detaches the contained widget. (ownership remains)
     * @return The contained widget
     */
    QWidget *detachWidget();

      private
slots:
    /**
     * @brief Toggles the visibility.
     */
    void toggleVisibility()
    {
        collapse(widget_->isVisible());
    }

      private:
    /**
     * @brief The contained widget
     */
    QWidget *widget_;

    /**
     * @brief The button to toggle the widget
     */
    QPushButton *button_;

    /**
     * @brief The layout containing the header and widget
     */
    util::ObserverPtr<QVBoxLayout> layout_;
}; // Collapsable
}
} // end namespaces qtutil, cvv

#endif // CVVISUAL_COLLAPSABLE_H
```

Comment: The error occurs in `../util/observer_ptr.hpp`. It likely is missing a `#include <stdexcept>`, because that is where `std::logic_error` is declared according to the standard.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I will look for this

Answer (score 1):

I will follow up the #include comment from @Cris Luengo as I would like to understand what went wrong with my build.

However I have also tracked down a different method for installation which I have just suceeded in testing.

The link is here
https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/126

A toolchain has been provided along with instructions on how to enable the option. I had both Visual Studio 2015 and 2019 installed before I found the site, I don't know if that made a difference but one of the comments said use 2015.

I followed the instructions to manually edit the setup.py file. I ran all the steps from the Windows command line as an administrator.

The home site provides pre-built versions of OpenCV without the non-free code and it is a copy of their toolchain that is used.
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/